# regex to ignore lines with comments and empty lines in a capture group using python

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to capture a group of messages between the start and stop while ignoring lines beginning with comments and empty lines.

***input text:***

```
 ================REPORT================
 
 Run Details 

==============================================
This belongs to xyz run: start of message

#comments about the message

Error details 1

Error details 2

Error details 3

# end of message

==============================================
 Run Time Information 

==============================================
```

I tried the below code but it captures lines with comments and empty lines

```
pattern = r".*start of message(?P<msg>[\w\W]*)# end of message"
matches = re.finditer(pattern, text)

for match in matches:
    print(match.group("msg"))
```

***output:***

```
#comments about the message

Error details 1

Error details 2

Error details 3
```

***Expected output:***

```
Error details 1
Error details 2
Error details 3
```

I tried using negative lookahead:

```
pattern = r".*start of message(?P<msg>(^(?!((#)|(\s))).*[\w\W]*))# end of message"
```

but it does not find matches.

Comment: There was a nice answer which is removed now. See [this Python demo](https://tio.run/##nVKxbsIwEJ3JV5zCYqMqEmVDQixl6NQqygZUCnBJLNnnyHeRoD@fOkA7RCzlLZae7PfevXN7kcbTou@Na30QCJgkgmeBFUxUCqsR8s3nR16M2R2lySSF@5F3BG8opbEcqRu5@hdub4rGMBzQeqoZxMP58g2hoyWwlDGpr8Ahc1njr8n06J1DEoby4DsBaXB8ZROCD3C6p5s/pl8f04s/H0A6PfB/ZshrW4VxCO9U@eBKMZ6erC3VSRI1wIGhuMisMnQygkGFVK0N63FvKput9XiY9AWG/etlAhEBOf6ErYVB1w66LquD71o11xm31og1hKw0mGqwjPmPTfTb8Wz7tePpPspZvb9qtcGQqKio@/4H).

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use just one regular expression, [this one will do](https://regex101.com/r/lQIiTv/1):

```
^(?=.*?# end of message)(?!.*?start of message)[^\s#].+?$
```

### Python code

```py
import re

text = '''\
================REPORT================
Run Details

==============================================
This belongs to xyz run: start of message

#comments about the message

Error details 1

Error details 2

Error details 3

# end of message

==============================================
 Run Time Information

==============================================
'''

matches = re.findall(r'^(?=.*?# end of message)(?!.*?start of message)[^\s#].+?$', text, flags=re.S|re.M)
print(matches)
```

***Output***

```
['Error details 1', 'Error details 2', 'Error details 3']
```

Anyhow, I would recommend to solve the problem in two steps:

1. Finding the group.
2. Filtering out the comments.